# Open file at compile-time [JS backend]

Tags: metaprogramming, nim-lang

I'm trying open file in macro, but I got exception:

```bash
template/generic instantiation of `some` from here
Error: cannot 'importc' variable at compile time; fopen
```

My Nim code:

```
import macros


macro some(): untyped =
  var f = open("some.txt")
  echo f.readAll()
  f.close()

some()
```

to compile:

```bash
nim js file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

`staticRead("some.txt")`